# JavaFX TableView - New Values in new Cell in same Row

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, coordinates

I've got following problem:

I styled a TableViews Cells into Rectangles. Now I want to add Objects with an X and Y Coordinate in it (`obj.getAblaufX()` and `obj.getAblaufY()`).
How can I add them correctly in JavaFX TableView?

My Current Code:

```
ObservableList<Event> eventList = loadEvents();
TableView<Event> tableView = new TableView<Event>();
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
tableView.setItems(eventList);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TableColumn<Event, String> tmpCol = new TableColumn<>();
        tmpCol.setId(Integer.toString(i));
        tmpCol.setMaxWidth(40);
        tmpCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ObservableValue<String>() {
            @Override
            public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super String> listener) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public String getValue() {
                if(Integer.parseInt(tmpCol.getId()) == cellData.getValue().getAblaufX()) {
                    return cellData.getValue().getAbteilung();
                } else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(tmpCol);
}
```

Result:

[image]

But:

**Object SP1 has X = 0 and Y = 0**

**Object SP2 has X = 1 and Y = 0**

So, how to fix this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Event` as item type, you pervent the `TableView` from displaying more than one `Event` per row. Use `Integer` as item type instead and store the values in a `ObservableMap<TablePos, Event>` where `TablePos` is a class containing the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
public final class TablePos {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public TablePos(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 17 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 17 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof TablePos)) {
            return false;
        }
        final TablePos other = (TablePos) obj;
        return (this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y);
    }

}
```

```
public class Event {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final IntegerProperty x;
    private final IntegerProperty y;

    public Event(String name, int x, int y) {
        // set beans for properties here to make this instance accessible to listeners
        this.y = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "y", y);
        this.x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "x", x);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name);
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public final void setName(String value) {
        this.name.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public final int getX() {
        return this.x.get();
    }

    public final void setX(int value) {
        this.x.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty xProperty() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public final int getY() {
        return this.y.get();
    }

    public final void setY(int value) {
        this.y.set(value);
    }

    public final IntegerProperty yProperty() {
        return this.y;
    }

}
```

```
private static void put(Map<TablePos, Event> map, Event evt) {
    map.put(new TablePos(evt.getX(), evt.getY()), evt);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ObservableMap<TablePos, Event> contents = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    TableView<Integer> tableView = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    TableColumn columnGroup = new TableColumn("Heutige Termine");

    ChangeListener<Number> xChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Event evt = (Event) ((Property) observable).getBean();
        TablePos oldPos = new TablePos(oldValue.intValue(), evt.getY());
        TablePos newPos = new TablePos(newValue.intValue(), evt.getY());
        contents.remove(oldPos);
        contents.put(newPos, evt);
    };

    ChangeListener<Number> yChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Event evt = (Event) ((Property) observable).getBean();
        TablePos oldPos = new TablePos(evt.getX(), oldValue.intValue());
        TablePos newPos = new TablePos(evt.getX(), newValue.intValue());
        contents.remove(oldPos);
        contents.put(newPos, evt);
    };

    contents.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends TablePos, ? extends Event> change) -> {
        if (change.wasRemoved()) {
            Event evt = change.getValueRemoved();
            evt.xProperty().removeListener(xChangeListener);
            evt.yProperty().removeListener(yChangeListener);
        }
        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            Event evt = change.getValueAdded();
            evt.xProperty().addListener(xChangeListener);
            evt.yProperty().addListener(yChangeListener);
        }

    });

    // items denote the y coordinate
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tableView.getItems().add(i);
    }

    // one column per x coordiante
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        TableColumn<Integer, String> column = new TableColumn<>();

        // take value from Map using x (index) and y (item value)
        column.setCellValueFactory(cd
                -> Bindings.selectString(
                        Bindings.valueAt(contents, new TablePos(index, cd.getValue())), "name"));

        columnGroup.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    tableView.getColumns().add(columnGroup);

    Event opTarget = new Event("Something", 2, 9);

    put(contents, new Event("SP1", 0, 0));
    put(contents, new Event("SP2", 1, 0));
    put(contents, opTarget);

    Button move = new Button("move");
    move.setOnAction(evt -> opTarget.setX(9 - opTarget.getX()));
    Button rename = new Button("rename");
    rename.setOnAction(evt -> opTarget.setName(opTarget.getName().equals("42") ? "Answer" : "42"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, tableView, move, rename));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that this requires you to know the number of rows/columns at the initialisation (I used 10 for both for simplicity). If this is not the case, you could add a listener to the `ObservableMap` that dynamically adds/removes rows / columns.

Comment: and yes, Event can be modified. I changed int to IntegerProperty. But how to add the listener?

Comment: @Mr.0x50: changed example to use a custom `Event` class updating positions on property change.

Comment: And I get following Error:
Jun 10, 2016 8:30:09 AM com.sun.javafx.binding.SelectBinding$SelectBindingHelper getObservableValue
WARNING: Exception while evaluating select-binding [abteilungProp]

Comment: @Mr.0x50: I don't understand the first comment. This just shows that a modification of the item position values will automatically adjust the key that is used for the mapping.In the second case you get warnings, not errors and unfortunately javafx uses it's own logger instead of java.util.logging and I do not know how to filter those logs,or if it's even possibleThis is very sad, since not being able to evaluate all steps is [documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#selectString-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.lang.String...-)